# Multiple image upload without flash

Tags: javascript, html, http-upload

I want to use HTML and PHP for 9 or more images upload. The problem is that I don't want 9 upload fields because it looks bad. Does anybody have any suggestions ? Maybe examples ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://the-stickman.com/web-development/javascript/upload-multiple-files-with-a-single-file-element/

Answer (score 5):

I've been using [noSWFUpload](http://code.google.com/p/noswfupload/) for some time and it works pretty good. It relies on XMLHttpRequest's `sendAsBinary` in supporting clients and falls back to iframe-based submission.

Answer (score 1):

Connect to the fileInput's onchange event, hide it, get the value and add it to a textarea,  and create another. Name them all the same plus an increment: field1, field2... Loop through the field names in PHP and check for existance with isset.

Or use Dojo's FileUploader and force html:
http://docs.dojocampus.org/dojox/form/FileUploader

Answer (score 0):

What I have done in the past is to give an option on doing another upload, or, when they pick the first file, display it as a label, then have another box ready for them to pick another file.  Each file input is actually with a unique name, so the server just goes through until it doesn't find the next file.

But, this requires a bit of javascripting. :)